# Reading first n lines of sheet using xlsx module

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I am trying to read first five rows of data from an excel sheet using xlsx module. 
Initially, I tried by using a sheet_to_json method which converts whole sheet data to an array of arrays.

```
let sheetData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetsList[i]], {
  header: 1,
  defval: '',
  blankrows: true
});
```

But the problem (out of memory) incurred when the file size is huge(>10K records present in a sheet).

Secondly, I tried using the following link: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/214#issuecomment-96843418
But I am getting the following error:

```
    f:\xxx\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:2774
function decode_range(range) { var x =range.split(":").map(decode_cell); return {s:x[0],e:x[x.length-1]}; }
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

How can I resolve it? or are they any other method or modules that are available such that I can get data from either csv, xlsx, xls?

Thanks!

Comment: You might look into "streaming" parsers for reading your input data. Such a parser would operate on chunks of the file at a time, so you wouldn't have any out of memory errors. Looks like [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-stream-reader) might do the trick.

Comment: @John Ellmore - Thanks for trying to help me out. But this will not solve my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can get the first n lines of the sheet with the help of the **sheetRows** option that is present.

So, the code looks as follows:

```
let workbook = xlsx.readFile(path, {sheetRows: 5})
 let sheetsList = workbook.SheetNames
 let sheetData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetsList[i]], {
      header: 1,
      defval: '',
      blankrows: true
 });
```

Here I have limited to first 5 rows.

Thanks to all who tried in solving this problem. Special thanks to xlsx community member. Here is the link: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/1225